# Can the initial Rummikub meld build on other player's tiles?

Tags: rummikub, joker

When playing the initial 30 points, can I use a tile from an existing meld on the board to complete my meld without using the points from that tile? For instance, I have a red 9, 11, and 12 in my rack, which is 32 points, but I need the red 10 on the board to play them. Is this a legal move?

Answer (score 12):

From the [rules](https://rummikub.com/rules/#classic-rules) (emphasis added):

> **After** players have made their initial plays, they can also build on other sets on the table...

I think this implies that **while** you are making your initial meld, you cannot use the existing melds.

Comment: My rules state: "the first set or sets must add up to a minimum of 30, you are not allowed to build upon, or manipulate any sets until you have laid down and entered the game". By you using another tile you are manipulating them.  Not a legal move sorry.

Comment: Sounds like there are multiple versions of the rules and they are in agreement (though some are written more clearly than others).

Answer (score 1):

You must have 30 points on your board only. You cannot use another player's tiles to make your 30 points for your 1st meld.