# Initial move in Rummikub

Tags: rummikub

In an initial move in Rummikub, can I go out by:

- making an inital meld with 30 or more points (made up of my own tiles),
- then continue (my first turn) by manipulating and adding tiles to the existing board.

Or must I wait until my next turn to manipulate and add tiles to the existing board?

Comment: Does https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/33542/13207 answer your question?

Comment: @chicks the question is similar, but there is a significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

The initial meld can only use tiles from the player rack. So it is not possible to extend the turn with tiles from the board. This is clear from [the Rummikub rules](https://rummikub.com/rules/#classic-rules):

The initial meld:

> In order to make an initial meld, each player must
> place tiles on the table in one or more sets that total at least 30
> points. These points must come from the tiles on each player’s rack;
> for their initial meld, players may not use tiles already played on
> the table.

The other turns:

> On turns after a player has made his/her initial meld, that player
> can build onto other sets on the table with tiles from his/her rack.

Answer (score 0):

As per Wikipedia "Players may not make their initial meld and along with that play on groups and runs during the same turn. You can play on runs and groups after the turn of making the initial meld."

Comment: The first sentence of that Wikipedia quote is unclear. It's unclear how it even parses.